# Antlr MismatchedSetException During Interpretation

Tags: java, antlr

I am new to Antlr and I have defined a basic grammar using Antlr 3. The grammar compiles and ANTLRWorks generates the Parser and Lexer code without any problems.

The grammar can be seen below:

```
grammar i;

@header {
package i;
}

module      : 'Module1'| 'Module2';
object      : 'I';
objectType  : 'Name';
filters         : EMPTY | 'WHERE' module;
table       : module object objectType;
STRING      : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
EMPTY           : ' ';
```

The problem is that when I interpret the table Parser I get a MismatchedSetException. This is due to having the EMPTY. As soon as I remove EMPTY from the grammar, the interpretation works. I have looked on the Antlr website and some other examples and the Empty space is ' '. I am not sure what to do. I need this EMPTY.

When it interprets, I get the following Exception:

```
Interpreting...
[11:02:14] problem matching token at 1:4 NoViableAltException(' '@[1:1: Tokens : ( T__4 | T__5 | T__6 | T__7 | T__8 | T__9 | T__10 | T__11 | T__12 | T__13 | T__14 | T__15 );])
[11:02:14] problem matching token at 1:9 NoViableAltException(' '@[1:1: Tokens : ( T__4 | T__5 | T__6 | T__7 | T__8 | T__9 | T__10 | T__11 | T__12 | T__13 | T__14 | T__15 );])
```

As soon as I change the EMPTY to be the following:

```
EMPTY : '';
```

instead of:

```
EMPTY : ' ';
```

It actually interprets it. However, I am getting the following Exception:

```
Interpreting...
[10:57:23] problem matching token at 1:4 NoViableAltException(' '@[1:1: Tokens : ( T__4 | T__5 | T__6 | T__7 | T__8 | T__9 | T__10 | T__11 | T__12 | T__13 | T__14 | T__15 | T__16 );])
[10:57:23] problem matching token at 1:9 NoViableAltException(' '@[1:1: Tokens : ( T__4 | T__5 | T__6 | T__7 | T__8 | T__9 | T__10 | T__11 | T__12 | T__13 | T__14 | T__15 | T__16 );])
```

However, ANLTWorks still generates the Lexer and Parser code.

I hope you can help.

EDIT:

```
grammar i;

@header {
package i;
}

select      : 'SELECT *' 'FROM' table filters';';
filters : EMPTY | 'WHERE' conditions;
conditions  : STRING operator value;
operator    : '=' | '!=';
true            : 'true';
value           : true;
STRING  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
EMPTY           : ' ';
```

Comment: I doubt that you need to explicitly capture whitespace, but I can't be sure without a better understanding of the usage. Could you give an example of how you plan to use the `filters` rule? E.g., what would the input look like if you wanted to use the `WHERE` keyword? Right now it isn't wired to another rule so an example would help.

Comment: Well, I am unable to give the full details. The above is just an example. I am developing a grammar for my company and the requirement is big. I am unable to provide any information. Are you able to help? Assumming, the whitespace is needed.

Comment: As stated above, this NoViableAltException still happens without the EMPTY.

Comment: When I think of a rule named `EMPTY`, I think of `filters: | 'WHERE' module;` (the rule `filters` is satisfied by "empty" input in the first alternative) and not `filters: ' ' | 'WHERE' module;'`(a single space for the first alt). As soon as you match whitespace explicitly (i.e., you're not skipping it), it has to be accounted for between keywords and everywhere else, so I'm scowling menacingly at that EMPTY rule. ;)

Comment: EMPTY is just an empty space. So what I would like to do is: when a user enters nothing, the grammar accepts it.

Comment: Roger that. I think we're talking about the same thing but in different terms. I'll have an answer posted shortly.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. Will look forward to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a bit unsure about usage, but I think we're talking about the same thing when we say "empty input". Here's an answer to get the ball rolling, starting with a modified grammar.

```
grammar i;

@header {
package i;
}

module      : 'Module1'| 'Module2';
object      : 'I';
objectType  : 'Name';
filters     : | 'WHERE' module;
table       : module object objectType filters;
STRING      : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
WS          : (' '|'\t'|'\f'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();}; //ignore whitespace
```

Note that I tacked `filters` onto the end of the `table` rule to explain what I'm talking about.

This grammar accepts the following input (starting with rule `table`) as it did before:

> Module1 I Name

It works because `filters` matches even though nothing follows the text `Name`: it matches on empty input using the first alternative.

The grammar also accepts this:

> Module1 I Name WHERE Module2

The `filters` rule is satisfied with the text `WHERE Module2` matching the second alternative (defined as `'WHERE' module` in the grammar).

A cleaner approach would be to change `filters` and `table` to the following rules (recognizing, of course, that I changed `table` in the first place).

```
filters     : 'WHERE' module; //no more '|' 
table       : module object objectType filters?; //added '?'
```

The grammar matches the same input as before, but the terms a little clearer: instead of saying "`filters` is required in `table` and `filters` matches on empty", we now say "`filters` are optional in `table` and `filters` doesn't match on empty".

It amounts to the same thing in this case. Matching on empty (`foo: | etc;`) is perfectly valid, but I've run into more problems using it than I have with matching optional (`foo?`) rules.

---

> Update following your update.

I'm taking a step back here to get us out of the theoretical and into the practical. Here is an updated grammar, Java test code that invokes it, test input, and test output. Please give it a run.

**Grammar** 
Altered for testing but follows the same idea as before.

```
grammar i;

@header {
 package i;
}


selects     : ( //test rule to allow processing multiple select calls. Don't worry about the details.
                {System.out.println(">>select");}
                select
                {System.out.println("<<select");}
               )+ 
            ; 

select      : 'SELECT *' 'FROM' table filters? ';'
              {System.out.println("\tFinished select.");}       //test output
            ;

module      : 'Module1'| 'Module2';
object      : 'I';
objectType  : 'Name';
filters     : 'WHERE' conditions
              {System.out.println("\tFinished filters.");}      //test output
            ;

table       : module object objectType
              {System.out.println("\tFinished table.");}        //test output
            ;

conditions  : STRING operator value
              {System.out.println("\tCondition test on " + $STRING.text);}
            ;
operator    : '=' | '!=';
true_       : 'true';       //changed so that Java code could be generated
value       : true_;
STRING      : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
WS          : (' '|'\t'|'\f'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();}; //ignore whitespace
```

**TestiGrammar.java**

```
package i;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

public class TestiGrammar {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStream resource = TestiGrammar.class.getResourceAsStream("itest.txt");

    CharStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(resource);

    resource.close();

    iLexer lexer = new iLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

    iParser parser = new iParser(tokens);
    parser.selects();
  }
}
```

**itest.txt** Test input file

```
SELECT * FROM Module2 I Name;
SELECT * FROM Module2 I Name WHERE foobar = true; 
SELECT * FROM Module2 I Name WHERE dingdong != true;
```

**test output**

```
>>select
    Finished table.
    Finished select.
<<select
>>select
    Finished table.
    Condition test on foobar
    Finished filters.
    Finished select.
<<select
>>select
    Finished table.
    Condition test on dingdong
    Finished filters.
    Finished select.
<<select
```

Comment: So does the '|' actually mean an empty space? So basically, I don't whether you know Java or not. But what I am trying to achieve is something like this: private String name; name = new String(" ");

Comment: @user1646481 The gap between the `:` and the `|` in `filters: | 'WHERE' module;` means "this rule is considered satisfied if nothing is read." (The new rule `WS` ensures that whitespace is skipped, so actual spaces are completely out of the picture: they are now effectively "empty input" or "non-input"). `filters` could be written as `filters: 'WHERE' module | ;`, putting that empty alternative at the end.

Comment: @user1646481 Re: `new String(" ")`: I'm comfortable with Java, but I would need an example that applies to your grammar to know for certain what you're asking for. Without that, we'll end up talking past each other. :/

Comment: ok, I have edited above. Please see the edit and let me know what you think. This should give you an idea of why empty string is required.

Comment: @user1646481 That helps, thank you. Is `SELECT * FROM Foo;` (no space before the semicolon, no filters provided) valid input? How about `SELECT <many spaces here> * <many spaces here too> From Foo;` with the extra spaces here and there?

Comment: It will be SELECT * FROM Table with no space before semilcolon. No spaces are allowed. So it will be SELECT * FROM Table or SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name = i; I have given filters. It is filters : EMPTY | WHERE conditions;

Comment: @user1646481 Please see the update to my answer. I want to make sure that you see what my version of the grammar is able to parse because it sounds like it's handling what you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I seem to understand this now. This works what I need, basically making it optional solves the empty character problem. Why do I still get an NoViableAntlException?

Comment: @user1646481 I'm glad I could help. What's the input and the error text you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks. The problem is stated in the original description. It starts with: problem matching token at then it gives the NoViableAltException. However, ANTLRWorks generates the Parser and Lexer code.

Comment: @user1646481 I think that's the `EMPTY` rule at work. The `WS` rule handles everything you need for whitespace.

Comment: The EMPTY has been taken out now and replaced with parser?. However, the WS is not included. If I add this, will it solve this problem?

Comment: @user1646481 Yeah, I think so. You have to account for whitespace between the keywords somehow, and the rule I provided is one of the easiest ways to handle it.

Comment: ok, it works. Thanks for your help. What does the skip() actaully do?

Comment: @user1646481 It tells the lexer to swallow the token that the rule would otherwise produce. In this case, it means that the lexer will read whitespace like any other lexer rule, but it will never pass the `WS` token to the parser (which means `WS` can never be part of a parser rule).

Comment: ok, thanks. So final thing is WS a keyword identified by Antlr? because it has solved this problem.

Comment: @user1646481 No, it's a lexer rule like any other. You could name it `FOOBAR` if you want. The lexer looks at spaces and newlines like any other type of input (letters, numbers, etc), so you need a rule like `WS` (or `FOOBAR`, if you like) to tell the lexer what to do with whitespace when it comes across them in the input.